# Gmail conversations missing in new Outlook.com account

Tags: gmail, outlook.com, outlook, office-365

I just signed up for a new Outlook.com account and synced my existing Gmail account with my Windows Live account. However, when I view my Gmail messages within Outlook.com the only messages that show up are from 2009 and prior.

How do I get all my messages to show up?

Answer (score 1):

I would try setting this first option, and then resyncing.
[image: Pop Download settings]
I'm thinking you might have checked the second option in 2009.

Comment: Oops, I read prior as after.